Sitecore Test Image Previews Not Displaying
I am facing one issue while using the AB Test in Sitecore 10.2.0
I checked the required configurations mentioned in the following article and found that all the configurations are already present. But after adding the AB test for any component "Preview and start test" is not displaying any data at all and I am not sure what is going wrong with it. Please let me know, what else I can do to get the proper output.
Configurations Article: https://www.sam-solutions.com/blog/sitecore-test-image-previews-not-displaying-what-to-do/
Perform AB Testing Steps Article: https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/setting-up-sitecore-personalization-second-step

Note: I am not able to find anything related to this in the logs but getting the below-shown error in the console and it is only occurring when I am using the AB Test.


Can you please share any error on the logs you are getting as well.

@ckhanna added the console error in the question as screenshot.

From the error it seems like __RequestVerificationToken cookie is not getting created. Can you check the cookie is there by going to the Application -> Cookies tab section from the developer tools.

In case the cookie is missing, check the httpCookies section inside the Web.config file. It should have httpOnlyCookies setting set to true.
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>

Hope this helps!!!
